# Cannot get scroll bars to appear on iframe

Tags: html, css, lightbox

I have an info popup on a web page. It contains an iframe, which shows the info. I cannot seem to get the vertical scroll bar to appear, so some of the content is not shown.

This is the html for the popup, as taken from the chrome dev tools (so presumably after jquery lightbox has waved its magic wand):

```
    <div id="lightbox" style="z-index: 10500; top: 1030.6px; left: 0px;">
        <div id="outerImageContainer" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 620px; display: block; height: 320px;">
             <div id="modalContainer" style="display: none; padding: 10px;"></div>
             <div id="frameContainer" style="padding: 10px;">
                 <iframe id="lightboxFrame" style="z-index: 10500;" frameborder="0" width="600px" height="300px" scrolling="no" src="Info.html?lang=grch&amp;item=436"></iframe>
            </div>
          <div id="imageContainer" style="display: none; padding: 10px;">
               <img id="lightboxImage" style="display: none;">
               <div id="hoverNav" style="display: none; z-index: 10500;">
                    <a id="prevLink" href="#" style="padding-top: 10px; display: none; height: 300px;"></a>
                    <a id="nextLink" href="#" style="padding-top: 10px; display: none; height: 300px;"></a>
               </div>
          </div>
          <div id="loading" style="z-index: 10500; display: none;">
               <a href="#" id="loadingLink"></a>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="imageDataContainer" class="clearfix" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: block; width: 620px;">
          <div id="imageData"><div id="frameHoverNav" style="display: block; z-index: 10500;">
            <a id="framePrevLink" href="#" style="padding-top: 10px; display: none;"></a>
            <a id="frameNextLink" href="#" style="padding-top: 10px; display: none;"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="imageDetails">
            <span id="caption" style="z-index: 10500;">&nbsp;</span>
            <span id="numberDisplay" style="display: none;"></span>
        </div>
        <div id="bottomNav">
            <a id="bottomNavClose" href="#" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">schließen</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

What I have tried:

- Removing the scrolling="no" from the iframe
- Setting scrolling="yes" on the iframe
- Adding a css style to the lightbox element and/or the iframe element : overflow: auto
- Adding a overflow: scroll to the lightbox and/or iframe elements.
- Adding an overflow: auto to all the elements
- Adding overflow: scroll to all the elements
- Saying nasty things to my screen
- Having a coffee
- Posting on SO

I'm not sure what is overriding the overflow property here. To quote the user, "it displays perfectly in IE", but not in FF or Chrome.

Comment: Did you check by giving `scrolling="yes"`? *Having a coffee* and *Posting on SO* are ultimate. :)

Comment: See if it works. If that works, will post an answer and you accept it. :)

Comment: Haha thanks. I just get so frustrated by annoying undebuggable css problems...

Comment: Sorry I meant the other thing. I did try that, but forgot to list it. If I set it to yes, I can scroll the text, but only by selecting and dragging. The scrollbar still does not appear.

Comment: What about setting width in CSS as well as HTML, 4 permutations. :)

Comment: No joy. This is quite strange.

Comment: Lemme try and get back to you...

Comment: This is working: http://jsfiddle.net/f8yMB/

Comment: Ok. I'll try to add the scrolling="yes" to the page on the server and see if that works.

Comment: If not, then the problem would be with that `Info.html`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `scrolling="yes"`:

```
    <div id="lightbox" style="z-index: 10500; top: 1030.6px; left: 0px;">
        <div id="outerImageContainer" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 620px; display: block; height: 320px;">
             <div id="modalContainer" style="display: none; padding: 10px;"></div>
             <div id="frameContainer" style="padding: 10px;">
                 <iframe id="lightboxFrame" style="z-index: 10500;" frameborder="0" width="600px" height="300px" scrolling="yes" src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_page"></iframe>
            </div>
          <div id="imageContainer" style="display: none; padding: 10px;">
               <img id="lightboxImage" style="display: none;">
               <div id="hoverNav" style="display: none; z-index: 10500;">
                    <a id="prevLink" href="#" style="padding-top: 10px; display: none; height: 300px;"></a>
                    <a id="nextLink" href="#" style="padding-top: 10px; display: none; height: 300px;"></a>
               </div>
          </div>
          <div id="loading" style="z-index: 10500; display: none;">
               <a href="#" id="loadingLink"></a>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="imageDataContainer" class="clearfix" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: block; width: 620px;">
          <div id="imageData"><div id="frameHoverNav" style="display: block; z-index: 10500;">
            <a id="framePrevLink" href="#" style="padding-top: 10px; display: none;"></a>
            <a id="frameNextLink" href="#" style="padding-top: 10px; display: none;"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="imageDetails">
            <span id="caption" style="z-index: 10500;">&nbsp;</span>
            <span id="numberDisplay" style="display: none;"></span>
        </div>
        <div id="bottomNav">
            <a id="bottomNavClose" href="#" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">schließen</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/f8yMB/

If not, then the problem is with the `info.html` page.

Comment: Ok, finally I removed the scrolling="yes" entirely. That did the trick. I'll accept your answer because it's basically the same.